# Accessing a Clip Inside Another Clip in a Loaded SWF-File

Tags: actionscript-3, hierarchical-data, movieclip

I'm writing a card game in AS3. The artist I'm working with has produced (in Flash CS4) a single swf-file containing all the card graphics and animations. The structure of the fla working file looks something like this:

```
- Scene
  - CardGraphics (Movie Clip)
    - CardFront
    - CardBack
    - CardValueImage (Movie Clip)
    ...
```

In the program I create 52 instances of my Card class, each having a MovieClip instance created from the loaded swf. The idea is to set the frame of the CardValueImage MovieClip to correspond to the Card instance's suit and rank member variables. However, I can't figure out how I access CardValueImage and call gotoAndStop (or whatever method I will need to call).

This is basically what I want to do:

```
// Card Class
[Embed(source = 'CardGraphics.swf')]
private static var CardsClip:Class;
private var clip:MovieClip = new CardsClip;

// Card Constructor
this.valueImageFrame = suit * 13 + rank; // Calculate which frame contains the
                                         // graphical representation of this card
this.clip.CardValueImage.gotoAndStop(valueImageFrame);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
this.clip.getChildByName('CardValueImage').gotoAndStop(valueImageFrame);
```

i'm not sure if CardValueImage is the instance name of the movieclip that you have inside CardGraphics, if it is then it should work :)

EDIT:
to access the timeline of a embedded swf you need a different approach, leave a code example, and a blog post that explains it in more detail.

```
package  
{
    import mx.core.ByteArrayAsset;

    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class App extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source = '../assets/CardGraphics.swf', mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        public static const CardsClip : Class;

        public var loader : Loader = new Loader;
        public var swfasset : ByteArrayAsset;
        public var clip : MovieClip;

        public function App()
        {
            swfasset = new CardsClip();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, loadCompleteListener, false, 0, true);
            loader.loadBytes(swfasset);
        }

        private function loadCompleteListener(e : Event) : void 
        {
            clip = MovieClip(loader.content);

            var cardsGraphics:MovieClip = MovieClip(clip.getChildByName('CardsGraphics'));
            var cardValueImage:MovieClip = MovieClip(cardsGraphics.getChildByName('CardValueImage'));

            cardValueImage.gotoAndStop(2);

            addChild(clip);
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.8bitrocket.com/newsdisplay.aspx?newspage=36607

*note that the code was changed to match your scenario.

Comment: I'm afraid the only child the clip has is a Loader object.

Comment: you are right, check again the answer above, i've updated with a different approach so you can gain access to the timeline of a embedded swf.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved it setting CardGraphics to be exported as a class in Flash CS4 and publishing to a swc-file. That way I can skip using 'Embed' and simply create an instance of CardGraphics direcly. The CardValueImage clip appears as a property of CardGraphics and I can call gotoAndStop like so:

var cg:CardGraphics = new CardGraphics;
cg.CardValueImage.gotoAndStop(...);

Answer (score 1):

`Object(a.contentLoaderInfo.content)`

For example, if you have a swf and want to access to a symbol with instance name `some_name`.

```
 package {
        import flash.display.Loader;
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.Event;
        public class Main extends Sprite
            {
              [Embed(source="assets/YourMovie.swf", mimeType="application/x-shockwave-flash")]
              private var ClassName:Class

              private var mov:MovieClip
              private var symbolFromSWF:MovieClip
              public function Main()
              {
                mov=new ClassName();
                mov.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComp);
                addChild(mov);
              }
              protected function onComp(event:Event):void
              {
                var a:Loader=Loader(mov.getChildAt(0));
                symbolFromSWF=Object(a.contentLoaderInfo.content).some_name;
              }
         }
    }
```